# AngualarJS2 Core Starter Kit Error at UseWebpackDevMiddleware

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

This is my package.json.

```
{
  "name": "Angular2Spa",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.9",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.5",
    "angular2-platform-node": "~2.1.0-rc.1",
    "angular2-universal": "~2.1.0-rc.1",
    "angular2-universal-polyfills": "~2.1.0-rc.1",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^2.0.3",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^1.0.11",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "css": "^2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "preboot": "^4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rxjs": "5.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "ts-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-externals-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.1"
  }
}
```

After updating to 2.4.9 I am get an error at in startup.cs

```
        app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
        {
            HotModuleReplacement = true
        });
```

The error is

Call to Node module failed with error: Error
    at webpack (c:\users\32514\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Angular2Material\Angular2Material\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:19:9)
    at attachWebpackDevMiddleware (c:\users\32514\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Angular2Material\Angular2Material\node_modules\aspnet-webpack\WebpackDevMiddleware.js:66:20)
    at c:\users\32514\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Angular2Material\Angular2Material\node_modules\aspnet-webpack\WebpackDevMiddleware.js:217:21
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Server. (c:\users\32514\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Angular2Material\Angular2Material\node_modules\aspnet-webpack\WebpackDevMiddleware.js:192:32)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at emitListeningNT (net.js:1290:10)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:11)

I have followed few work arounds that are described here but none solved my issue. Does anyone know a work around a fix for this that actually works?